# cbpowell/MarqueeLabel, using StoryBoards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am using `cbpowell/MarqueeLabel` class in my project. I changed the class of a Label from `UILabel` to `MarqeeLabel`. This got my Label to scroll. But it is in its Default `MLLeftRight`. I need to change it to `MLContinous`. How can I make this happen? I tried add a User Defined RunTime attribute, but that doesn't work. I cannot add "`marqueeType`" in the program, because my label is still in the `UILabel` class instead of `MarqueeLabel`, so can only access the methods for `UILabel`.

Anyone with experience in `MarqueeLabel`, please advice.

Or if you can tell me, how I can access the methods of a custom class I set(here- `MarqueeLabel`) for my label (instead of- `UILabel`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `IBOutlet` for `MarqueeLabel` like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MarqueeLabel *mLabel;
```

Since it deoesn't support `IBInspectable` for marqueeType, you can configure label like

```
self.mLabel.marqueeType = MLLeftRight;
```